# Required Salesforce code version control, build & deployment tool

Tags: version-control, salesforce

Required Salesforce code version control, build & deployment tool. Please let me know if anyone worked integration this & any licensed/open souce tools available?

Comment: Per the close reasons, asking for tool recommendations is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this tool. A salesforce release management tool, which supports version controlling, automated deployements, build test automation etc..

([salesforce continuous integration and release management tool](http://www.autorabit.com))

Regards,

Naveen

Comment: Thanks Naveen. It's great tool & looks like it would deliver all that I need.

Answer (score 1):

eclipse + SVN or Git

[How To Use Git, GitHub and the Force.com IDE with Open Source Labs Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/labs/2011/04/how-to-use-git-github-force-com-ide-open-source-labs-apps.html)

[Using Force.com with Subversion for Team Development](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Force.com_with_Subversion_for_Team_Development)

[Salesforce + Git + Eclipse + EGIT = Better and Distributed Source Control](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-git-eclipse-egit-better-and-distributed-source-control/)

Answer (score 0):

You could just flosum for all the needs that you have stated above.